# Circular dependency trying to validate typeorm entity

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, class-validator

Having an entity like this:

```
import { UniqueOrganizationPrincipal } from './constraints/unique-organization-principal';
import { Role } from './role.entity';

@Entity()
export class UserOrganization {
  @ManyToOne(type => Role, role => role.userOrganizations, { nullable: false, eager: true })
  @UniqueOrganizationPrincipal()
  role: Role;

  ... other fields ...
}
```

and a custom validation class

```
import { Role } from '../role.entity';
import { UserOrganizationService } from '../user-organization.service';

@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
@Injectable()
export class UniqueOrganizationPrincipalConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  constructor(
    @Inject('UserOrganizationService') private readonly userService: UserOrganizationService
  ) { }


 async validate(role: Role, args: ValidationArguments) {
   .....
 }

  defaultMessage() {
    return 'error here';
  }
}

export function UniqueOrganizationPrincipal(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return (object: object, propertyName: string) => {
    registerDecorator({
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      constraints: [],
      validator: UniqueOrganizationPrincipalConstraint
    });
  };
}
```

and a service that injects the entity's repository

```
@Injectable()
export class UserOrganizationService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserOrganization)
    private readonly userOrganizationRepository: Repository<UserOrganization>
  ) {}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
/project/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/common/typeorm.utils.js:14
        throw new circular_dependency_exception_1.CircularDependencyException('@InjectRepository()');
              ^
Error: A circular dependency has been detected inside @InjectRepository(). Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()". Also, try to eliminate barrel files because they can lead to an unexpected behavior too.
    at Object.getRepositoryToken (/project/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/common/typeorm.utils.js:14:15)
    at Object.exports.InjectRepository (/project/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/common/typeorm.decorators.js:6:130)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/project/src/user/user-organization.service.ts:14:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/project/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/project/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
```

since for my validation logic I need to run a query and so at least inject the service or the repository, how am I supposed to get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by using `ModuleRef` during the validation check

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
@Injectable()
export class UniqueOrganizationPrincipalConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  private userOrganizationService: UserOrganizationService;

  constructor(private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef) { }

  async validate(role: Role, args: ValidationArguments) {
    if (!this.userOrganizationService) {
      this.userOrganizationService = this.moduleRef.get('UserOrganizationService');
    }
    ... other code...
  }
}
```

Docs about `ModuleRef` can be found here

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency#module-reference

Comment: I think `forwardRef`could have also worked for you https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency

Comment: @FWoelffel but how would I use forwardRef on the entity, which is the one with the validation?

Comment: My bad, you can't. Forget what I suggested, it wouldn't work in your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a week trying to solve a problem like this. So I solved this problem, just changed my repository method that saves the entity. **I used repository.save (entity) and always failed with cyclic dependency.**

After switching to
repository.createQueryBuilder()
.insert()
.into(TABLE_NAME)
.values(entity)
.execute();
This error has been cleared. I really recommend trying to change the repository method, **because the save() method waits for the full entity set and createQueryBuilder() takes the entity values and turns them into string values, making a normal query.**

**I was using serverless and webpack. Typeorm does not work well with webpack.**